# How to attach Test failure screenshots to Azure Pipeline Test Run in YAML?

Tags: azure, yaml, pipeline, ui-automation, testcafe

I have made some automated test (Testcafe) and put them together in one of my VS projects folder as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFFfG.png).

1.Script to run and take screenshots on failure:

```
script: testcafe chrome **/Tests/**/* -S -s takeOnFails=true --reporter spec,xunit:report.xml
displayName: Run tests and save screenshots
continueOnError: true
```

2.Script for publishing:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
   displayName: Publish test results
   continueOnError: true
   inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/report.xml'
    searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    publishRunAttachments: true
    testRunTitle: "Task Results"
    failTaskOnFailedTests: false
```

3.Script for copying files and build artifact:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: '**/?(*.png)'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: Saved failure screenshots
```

Is there any way to add screenshots as attachment on test run created at step 2 like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzxUD.png) using Yaml?

Currently screenshots can be seen at artifact result from step 3 but I want them to be attached to test run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save screenshots and videos as attachments in Azure Build Pipeline with TestCafe and Yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67247685/how-can-i-save-screenshots-and-videos-as-attachments-in-azure-build-pipeline-wit)

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps does not support attachments (other than the test result file) if you use the JUnit or xUnit report format. See [Capture Screenshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/collect-screenshots-and-video?view=azure-devops&tabs=nunit#capture-screenshots) in the Azure docs.

To upload screenshots as attachments with the Publish Test Results task, you need to generate an NUnit 3.0 report. You may want to take a look at this community-developed TestCafe reporter for NUnit 3.0: https://github.com/NickLargen/testcafe-reporter-nunit3

According to the reporter's documentation, it can include videos and screenshots as test case attachments. Please note that since this plugin is supported by the community, we cannot promise that it will work as expected in all cases.